# How to set the value of a cell to Sum of the cell and e.parameter

Tags: google-apps-script

How can I get the value of a spreadsheet cell and add the value of an e.parameter to it and set the value of the cell to the total?

I've tried setting the formula of the cell to SUM() but I am not sure of how to write in the variables. When I try the cell value returns an error of unknown name range.

Or perhaps there is an easier way to do this that I am missing?

```js
doPost(e)
{
    if(e.parameter.transaction)
       {
        
         var cell = sheet.getRange(1,4);  
        var total = cell.getValue();
         cell.setFormula("=SUM(total:e.parameter.transaction)");
         
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of the parameter won't survive after it was called.
Your set Formula call will set the formula to that exact string.

Since what you are trying to do would be a circular reference you need to overwrite the value in the cell

```
cell.setValue(total+e.parameter.transaction)
```

Comment: I tried that too but e.parameter appends itself to the cell's value instead off adding the values together.

For example:

total = 32
e.paramaeter.transaction =  43

32 + 43 = 75

When I write cell.setValue(total+e.parameter.transaction) it instead sets the value of the cell to 3243.

Comment: Ah I got it to work by parsing the variables to integer with parseInt(). Thank you!